# Printf without newline in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, newline, printf, nasm

I've recently read this article on using printf and scanf in assembly:

[Meaning of intfmt: db "%d", 10, 0 in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479972/meaning-of-intfmt-db-d-10-0-in-assembly)

In particular it says 
"In printf, the newline prints a newline and then (if the output is in line buffered mode, which it probably is), flushes the internal output buffer so you can actually see the result. So when you remove the 10, there's no flush and you don't see the output."

However I do not know what to do if I do not want a newline after my output in my assembly file.
Here's a simple test file I've written to try printing without a newline:

```
extern printf


LINUX        equ     80H      ; interupt number for entering Linux kernel
EXIT         equ     60       ; Linux system call 1 i.e. exit ()




section .data
    int_output_format: db "%ld", 0


segment .text
    global  main


main:
    mov r8, 10
    push rdi
    push rsi
    push r10
    push r9
    mov rsi, r8
    mov rdi, int_output_format
    xor rax, rax
    call printf
    pop r9
    pop r10
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    call os_return      ; return to operating system


os_return:
    mov  rax, EXIT      ; Linux system call 1 i.e. exit ()
    mov  rdi, 0     ; Error code 0 i.e. no errors
    syscall     ; Interrupt Linux kernel 64-bit
```

but as the article I've read suggests stdout isn't being flushed. I was thinking perhaps I need to somehow flush after I output the number? But I'm really not sure.

I am using the NASM assembly language.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[fflush()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) flushes buffered output in line or full-buffered stdio streams:

```
extern fflush
...
xor  edi, edi          ; RDI = 0
call fflush            ; fflush(NULL) flushes all streams
...
```

Alternatively, `mov rdi, [stdout]` / `call fflush` also works to flush only that stream.  (Use `default rel` for efficient RIP-relative addressing, and you'll need `extern stdout` as well.)

Comment: `fflush` takes a FILE* arg (in RDI).  You need to zero RDI, not RAX, to pass it a NULL pointer (which means flush all open streams), or you need to `mov rdi, [rel stdout]` to load that specific global variable's value.  fflush isn't variadic so it doesn't care about the value of AL.  (edit: I'll just fix that myself)

Comment: Generally if you're using stdio calls from libc, you should exit with `call exit`, rather than a raw _exit system call.

Answer (score 3):

Call `fflush(stdout);` to display what's currently sitting in the buffers.

Comment: I think that's the c syntax? I'm looking for how to call it in assembly.

Comment: Per the C standard, `stdout` is a macro that expands into an expression of type `FILE*`. I don't know how it's defined in your compiler. You need to extract the value from `stdio.h`.

Comment: And you can call `fflush(NULL)` which is easier in assembly code, perhaps `xor %eax, %eax; call fflush`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You're right! I've completely forgotten about that special behavior.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Correct. I recommend writing this as a separate answer so Sarah can mark this as the answer she needed!

Comment: This looks like too much like C to me?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: fflush takes it's arguments on the stack like other C functions, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755027/how-come-exit0-exiting-by-syscall-prevents-me-from-receiving-any-stdout-con

Comment: on x86-64/Linux, some arguments are passed thru registers.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 32-bit mode (FASM):

```
push [_iob]
call [fflush]   ; call into DLL.  Callee-pops calling convention
```

GNU/Linux 32-bit mode (NASM)

```
extern fflush
extern stdout
...
push dword [stdout]
call fflush            ; linker takes care of PLT stub for dynamic linking (in a non-PIE executable)
add  esp, 4            ; caller-pops calling convention
etc...
```

Comment: How would you accomplish this in NASM? Is it the same?

Comment: I assume that FASM code is for Windows?  Linux glibc doesn't define it, and the calling convention looks Windowsy.  FASM works perfectly fine on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility would be to remove the default line buffering of the `stdout`stream. Here the C call to do that. Translation to assembly let as exercice, as I don't think it makes even sense to do file/stream I/O in ASM, the cost/benefit is tremendously wrong.

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This way every `printf` (and `fputs`, `putc`, `puts` etc...)  would have an implicit `fflush`

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for those searching a fast bypass to the problem, not an actual fix.

I was attempting to output the number 1234 one digit at a time and encountered the same issue as those here. After having no success with the mentioned solutions, and not wanting to spend more than a few minutes on this, I have found an easy way to display the number.

In your output string formats, simply have an output string that is an empty line (with the newline ofcourse).

```
Digit_out: db "%u", 0
Number_end: db "", 10, 0
```

Output as you would; in my case I had 4 pushes of digit_out (with 4 pushes of the digits themselves) and 4 calls to printf.

Once this is done, push Number_end and do a final call to printf. The entire number will then show :)

Comment: TL:DR: just print a newline eventually, before exiting, with any stdio function.  Yes, this works as long as your stdout is a terminal, not redirected to a file or pipe (which would make it default to full-buffered).  Normally you want your output to end with a newline anyway, but you should *also* exit with `call exit` (or `ret` from `main`) if you've been using stdio functions, not a raw `_exit` syscall.  Then your program will work consistently even when outputting to a regular file or other non-terminal.