# How come _exit(0) (exiting by syscall) prevents me from receiving any stdout content?

Tags: linux, assembly, interrupt, system-calls, gnu-assembler

I have a Linux x86-32 GAS assembly program terminating like this:

```
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx # argument for _exit
int $0x80
```

When I exit like this, the program functions like normally, but if I try to read the stdout output, I get nothing (using i.e. less or wc).

I tried compiling a minimal C program and comparing the strace outputs. The only difference I found was, that GCC made the C program (`int main() { printf("donkey\n"); }`) implicitely exit with `exit_group(0)` in the strace output.

I tried modifying my ASM program to exit with `call exit` instead of the raw syscall. The stdout was now readable as normal.

**Test case**

```
.data
douout: .string "monkey\n"
.text
.globl main

main:

pushl $douout
call printf
# Exit
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

Compile and run:

```
$ yasm -g dwarf2 -f elf -p gas t.asm && gcc -g -melf_i386 -o t t.o && ./t | wc -c
0
```

Expected:

```
7
```

EDIT:

I tried calling both `tcflush` and `fflush`, and I still have the problem. With `fflush` I even get a segfault.

```
0xb7e9e7c9 in _IO_fflush (fp=0x804a018) at iofflush.c:42
42  iofflush.c: No such file or directory.
    in iofflush.c
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7e9e7c9 in _IO_fflush (fp=0x804a018) at iofflush.c:42
#1  0x08048434 in main () at t.asm:12
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x08048434 in main () at t.asm:12
12  call fflush
(gdb) list
7   
8   pushl $douout
9   call printf
10  # Exit
11  movl $0, %eax
12  call fflush
13  movl $1, %eax
14  movl $0, %ebx
15  int $0x80
```

EDIT2:

Okay, it works now everyone. I was using the wrong calling convention that I copied from here: [Printf without newline in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502945/printf-without-newline-in-assembly)

The argument for `fflush` should be on the stack, as usual.

```
$ cat t.asm 
.data
douout: .string "monkey\n"
.text
.globl main

main:

pushl $douout
call printf
# Exit
pushl $0
call fflush
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
$ yasm -g dwarf2 -f elf -p gas t.asm && gcc -g -melf_i386 -o t t.o && ./t | wc -c
7
$
```

Thanks everyone, especially nos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you pipe stdout to wc, stdout becomes fully buffered.

_exit terminates the process immediately and does not run atexit() and other cleanup handlers. The runtime will register such handlers to be run on exit that flushes open FILE*, such as stdout. When those handlers does not get executed on exit, buffered data will be lost.

You should see output if you call `fflush(stdout)` after the printf call, or if you just run the program in a consol without piping the output to another program - in which case stdout will normally be line buffered, so stdout is flushed whenever you write a \n

Comment: How would you call ``fflush(stdout)``? According to ``unistd.h`` the fileno is 1, but according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502945/printf-without-newline-in-assembly , it is 0.

Comment: stdout in this context is the global FILE* named stdout(that by default is connected to file descriptor 1, standard out.). You can't use file descriptors, 0 nor 1, as arguments to functions that expect a FILE*. You can call fflush() with NULL as an argument to flush all open FILE* though.

Comment: But I didn't think there was a NULL in assembly? And in C, NULL == 0. How would it know the difference?

Comment: You wouldn't. You'd just use a 0 with the same size as a pointer. But that does not mean the file descriptor 0,  though their values are the same.

Comment: Scratch that, of course it would know the difference since it takes a FILE* and not a file descriptor.

Comment: Yeah, I know they are indistinguishable. I was confusing file descriptors and FILE* and I thought that it took a file descriptor. That's why I said "scratch that", to let you know that I knew how it would know the difference (because the FILE* for stdout isn't NULL, the file descriptor is 0, which usually equals NULL, however). I understand how it works now. Mange tak for hjælpen, kære nordmand :)

Answer (score 2):

Output sent to standard out is usually buffered.  If you call `fflush(stdout)` before you call `_exit` you should get your output.

The reason `exit` works is because that function is guaranteed to close and flush any open streams (such as stdout) before calling `_exit` itself to actually terminate the program.

Comment: But I do get the output if I do not pipe it. Also, ``man _exit`` notes that I can use ``tcflush``. I tried that, and it didn't work. How do I call ``fflush(stdout)``? ``pushl $1; call fflush``?

Comment: I found the stdout fileno in ``unistd.h``. Also, I just tried it with the 1 in stack and in ``%eax``, both of them segfault.

Comment: Reply to myself: It takes a FILE*, not a file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page for `_exit(2)`

> Whether it flushes standard I/O buffers and removes temporary files
>   created with tmpfile(3) is implementation-dependent. On the other
>   hand, _exit() does close open file descriptors, and this may cause an
>   unknown delay, waiting for pending output to finish. If the delay is
>   undesired, it may be useful to call functions like tcflush(3) before
>   calling _exit(). Whether any pending I/O is canceled, and which
>   pending I/O may be canceled upon _exit(), is implementation-dependent.

So unless you've flushed stdout, it may get discarded.

Comment: I tried calling ``tcflush``, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: tcflush works at on a terminal device. You need to to call fflush(stdout). (stdout is the global FILE* managed by libc, you cannot use the filedescriptor). If you're havng trouble with that, call fflush(NULL), which will flush all FILE*'s

Comment: You're not passing the right argument to fflush, as per the usual calling convention, the arguments should be on the stack, not in %eax