# Nasm segmentation fault on RET in _start

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .text
     global _start
_start:
     nop
main:
     mov eax, 1
     mov ebx, 2
     xor eax, eax
     ret
```

I compile with these commands:

```
nasm -f elf main.asm
ld -melf_i386 -o main main.o
```

When I run the code, Linux throw a segmentation fault error

(I am using Linux Mint Nadia 64 bits). Why this error is produced?

Comment: Should be the return code not be something like this (Linux):
   `mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 80h`
On my opinion you are getting the segmentation fault due to the `ret` in the last line.

Comment: Related: [What happens if there is no exit system call in an assembly program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49674026)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `ret` is **NOT** the proper way to exit a program in Linux, Windows, or Mac!!!!

**`_start` is not a function, there is no return address on the stack** because there is no user-space caller to return to.  Execution in user-space started here (in a static executable), at the process entry point.  (Or with dynamic linking, it jumped here after the dynamic linker finished, but same result).

On Linux / OS X, the stack pointer is pointing at `argc` on entry to `_start` (see the i386 or x86-64 System V ABI doc for more details on the process startup environment); the kernel puts command line args into user-space stack memory before starting user-space.  (So if you do try to `ret`, EIP/RIP = argc = a small integer, not a valid address.  If your debugger shows a fault at address `0x00000001` or something, that's why.)

---

For Windows it is `ExitProcess` and Linux is is system call -
`int 80H` using `sys_exit`, for x86 or using `syscall` using `60` for 64-bit or a call to `exit` from the C Library if you are linking to it.

##### 32-bit Linux (i386)

```
%define  SYS_exit  1   ; call number __NR_exit from <asm/unistd_32.h>

mov     eax, SYS_exit  ; use the NASM macro we defined earlier
xor     ebx, ebx       ; ebx = 0  exit status
int     80H            ; _exit(0)
```

##### 64-bit Linux (amd64)

```
mov     rax, 60        ; SYS_exit aka __NR_exit from asm/unistd_64.h
xor     rdi, rdi       ; edi = 0  first arg to 64-bit system calls
syscall                ; _exit(0)
```

(In GAS you can actually `#include <sys/syscall.h>` or `<asm/unistd.h>` to get the right numbers for the mode you're assembling a `.S` for, but NASM can't easily use the C preprocessor.
See [Polygot include file for nasm/yasm and C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922099/polygot-include-file-for-nasm-yasm-and-c) for hints.)

##### 32-bit Windows (x86)

```
push    0
call    ExitProcess
```

---

#### Or Windows/Linux linking against the C Library

```
; pass an int exit_status as appropriate for the calling convention
; push 0   /  xor edi,edi  /  xor ecx,ecx
call    exit
```

(Or for 32-bit x86 Windows, `call  _exit`, because C names get prepended with an underscore, unlike in x86-64 Windows.  The POSIX `_exit` function would be `call __exit`, if Windows had one.)

Windows x64's calling convention includes shadow space which the caller has to reserve, but `exit` isn't going to return so it's ok to let it step on that space above its return address.  Also, 16-byte stack alignment is required by the calling convention before `call exit` except for 32-bit Windows, but often won't actually crash for a simple function like `exit()`.

---

**`call exit` (unlike a raw exit system call or libc `_exit`) will flush stdio buffers first**.  If you used `printf` from `_start`, use `exit` to make sure all output is printed before you exit, even if stdout is redirected to a file (making stdout full-buffered, not line-buffered).

It's generally recommended that if you use libc functions, you write a `main` function and link with gcc so it's called by the normal CRT start functions which you can `ret` to.

See also

- [Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit)
- [How come _exit(0) (exiting by syscall) prevents me from receiving any stdout content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755027/how-come-exit0-exiting-by-syscall-prevents-me-from-receiving-any-stdout-con)

Defining `main` as something that `_start` falls through into doesn't make it special, it's just confusing to use a `main` label if it's not like a C `main` function called by a `_start` that's prepared to exit after `main` returns.

Comment: @maxiperez Not a stupid question at all :). It shows that programs are not just a 'main' functions and that they interact with the OS in different ways.

Comment: In your x64 Linux and Windows examples, I suppose you are returning a 0 exit code? If it were equivalent to the x86 version, that would be `mov rdi, sys_exit`?
And similarly, `push sys_exit` for the Windows version?

Comment: @odalet: Yes, the first 3 examples were returning 0.  But no, `sys_exit` is the call number, not the exit status. (And a non-standard macro name for the call number; `sys_exit` is the name of the Linux kernel function that implements it; `SYS_exit` and `__NR_exit` are CPP macros with the actual number.)  I edited this answer again with more/better comments, including one about setting the exit status before `call exit`.