# Polygot include file for nasm/yasm and C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, yasm

I have a bunch of magic numbers that I would like to include in both a C program and an assembly file to be compiled by nasm or yasm.

In plain C the file would look something a series of defines, like:

```
#define BLESS   55378008
#define ANSWER        42
...
```

In nasm or yasm, the same include could be implemented as:

```
%define BLESS   55378008
%define ANSWER        42
...
```

The only difference is that leading character before the `define`: `#` for C and `%` for nasm.

Is there any way to write a polygot include that allows me to include it in both C and nasm and only list the constants once?

<sub>Yes, I'm aware that I could just use `sed` or whatever to generate one file from the other.</sub>

Comment: You can run also C preprocessor over the asm file, including the only-#define C header.

Comment: Without some external tool, the answer is no. This has been an ongoing question in the NASM forums for years and there is no way without some external parsing to do what you want. NASM has a contributor based project called h2incn. Many external options m4, cpp, sed etc.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - if you write that as an answer it would be accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*NASM* by itself has no way to include *C* header files in assembly code. This has been [brought up in the *NASM* forum](https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1149.0) through the years. You will need an external tool to parse the *C* header files into something usable with *NASM* assembly syntax.

One such 3rd party contribution that is suppose to be compatible with *NASM* is [`h2incn`](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/h2incn/code/trunk/). I haven't tested it thoroughly enough so can't say it is stable or usable enough for all use cases.

The alternative is to pre-process the files with other tools like [`m4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)), [`cpp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), or even translating with [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

Comment: Has anything changed in the latest version of NASM? Or it is still required to run some external C-header files preprocessor to convert it into a NASM defines?

Comment: @St.Antario Nothing has changed, a third party utility is still required.