# Array indexing, problems with codes 11 and 10

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have a **following code**, running on the jdoodle.com:

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
    mov     eax, [array]
    mov     ebx, [array+1]
    add     eax, ebx
    mov     [sum], eax
    jmp     .printthis
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80
    ret

.printthis:
    mov     ecx, sum
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80
    ret

section .data
    array   db 1,2,3,4,5

segment .bss
    sum     resb 1
```

**After** compilation I have the following error:

```
Command terminated by signal 11
```

**Note**:
I've tried

> mov eax, [array+1*4]

and even

> mov eax, [array*4] ; which is an error, obvious, but I can't understand why

**Now to the question**
I have some programming experience, but started learning assembly recently. This error, 11 seg fault, gives me a little. I would appreciate if you share your knowledge on this topic or recommend some good material to read.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Your variables are bytes but you use dword registers. Fix one or the other. Also note that `write` syscall will not convert your number to text. `jmp .printthis` should be `call .printthis` (that is likely the cause of the fault, the `ret` has nowhere to return to)

Comment: At which instruction does the crash occur? You mention that you've tried modifying one of the `mov`s, but have you verified that that's actually the instruction that triggers the crash? Side note, you've only reserved one byte of space for `sum` but you write 4 bytes (`eax`) to it.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense.

Comment: @Jester, @Michael Guys, thank you so much! I've changed `mov eax, [array+1]` to it's right representation when working with Words - `mov eax, [array+1*4]`, and now it works. As well it seems like I need to learn about `jmp` and `call` alongside conversion from number to string.

Comment: `[array+1*4]` accesses more bytes than `array` contains.  What is this program actually supposed to do?

Comment: `jmp` to a `ret` in a non-function like `_start` is sort of a duplicate of [Nasm segmentation fault on RET in \_start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19760002) and/or [What if there is no return statement in a CALLed block of code in assembly programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205054).