# getting 'Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.' when trying to swap elements of array in masm

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, masm

Im trying to swap 2nd , 3rd elements of array using masm. I have already asked this quеstion, but i have rewritten program in masm so i think it qualifies for a new question.

Heres the code: I am getting 'Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.' message

```
.386
.MODEL flat
.CODE
_start:

    mov ebx, offset A
    mov ax, [ebx+2]
    mov dx, [ebx+4]
    mov [ebx+2], dx
    mov [ebx+4], ax
    ret   
.DATA
    A dw 1, 33, 1, 1, 1
end _start
```

Comment: In masm syntax you want something like `mov ebx, offset A`

Comment: *Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault* sounds like you're running it on Linux or maybe MacOS.  Not Windows; Windows doesn't have SIGSEGV; an invalid page fault would give a different error in Windows, like an "access violation" or something.  I don't think MASM can build a native Linux executable, so what are you actually doing?  Are you using JWASM?

Comment: Anyway, if it's still running on Linux, you can't `ret` from `_start` to exit, only from `main` (and then only if you're linking the CRT start files).  See [segmentation fault on RET in \_start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19760002)

Comment: I compile аnd link it using qeditor consolе build all command. @PeterCordes

Comment: What the heck is qeditor, and what shell commands does it use to build?  And what OS are you running it on?  After fixing it to use `mov ebx, offset A` to get the address like NASM `mov ebx, A`, what do you see when you run it under GDB, assuming it still segfaults?

Comment: I compiled it manually. I run it on windows 10. Used following: 
ml.exe /c /coff vb.asm
link.exe /subsystem:windows vb.obj

It now finished with following:
[Inferior 1 (process 24404) exited with code 06200041]

Comment: That is not an error, you just did not set an exit code. If you put e.g. `xor eax, eax` before the `ret` you should get an exit code of `0` (commonly used to mean normal termination).

Comment: So you were getting `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.` on Windows 10?  I'm surprised.  I don't think Windows has POSIX signals like SIGSEGV, so maybe your shell is making things up.

Comment: Аll questions to gdb.  @PeterCordes

Comment: Ok, I could imagine GDB pretending that it's POSIX, especially if you're using cygwin GDB so there actually are POSIX signals.