# Print values of variables on a line (without new line)

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

So, i faced with a problem, that print each value of variable on a new line, but format for print is a line. I really spend a lot of time that find solution. But this solution don't work. I think that is because i am noob in assembler. So, i deleted all my fail... This is my code:

```
global main
extern printf
section .data
str: db "%i", 10, 0
count: dw 1

section .text
main:
start:
push dword [count]
push dword str
call printf
push dword [count]
push dword str
call printf
```

So, now in terminal printed this:

```
1
1
```

What do I need to do to print like this:

```
1 1
```

Please, example me code, that i understand.... Please, don't send me first link in internet with similar problem, because i tried this. I really don't understand...
How i can insert in print string with differents char, for example ':', 'space', '/' and other...?
Thanks you :)

Comment: The `10` in the definition of `str` acts as an U+000A Line Feed, which is used as a linebreak.

Comment: @ecm I know. I tried delete it, but after this str does not print

Comment: I use linux x86 (Virtual Machine)

Comment: You probably need to flush the C library's buffers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502945/printf-without-newline-in-assembly?r=SearchResults

Comment: @ecm I tried this but nothing happens. If you can show me how to apply to my code, I will be very grateful

Comment: @ecm I found the code on the Internet, adjusted it to my own, but it displayed unchanged, or nothing at all print. I don't understand how it works

Comment: I updated some of the answers on the question @ecm linked; [Printf without newline in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8503215) has NASM code that works on Linux, so you can flush the buffers to see printf output even after removing the newline from the format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
str: db "%i", 10, 0
```

to

```
str: db "%i ", 0
```

`10` is a newline character. This replaces it with a space.

Comment: The file compiles but does not output anything. That is, if 10, 0, then displays ifnomation, if you remove 10, then nothing is displayed at all

Comment: Make sure you call `exit()` at the end of the program so that the buffer will be flushed.